# Why is that interest amortization is not taking place in my PHP Code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a script which amortize my interest using that formula for loan amortization. But i only want to amortize interest and insert it into database. 
The problem i am facing with my procedure is that interest is not reducing as it suppose to do. I want it to produce results like below on the column of amo_intr in database

```html
amo_intr 
12.00 
11.50 
10.95 
10.32 
9.62 
8.84 
7.96 
6.98 
5.88 
4.65 
3.27 
1.73
```

But instead i am getting results like on the image:[databaseresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Ufb.jpg)
I need help dont comment about mysql syntax i know its depricated'.
THIS IS MY PHP code to insert values into database:

```html
 <?php
include("connection/db_con.php");
$nn=11;
$install=16.14;
$edat='2016-03-15';
$amt=100;
$i=0.12;
$actual_l='L8080';
$ecn='R555555';
$amo_intr=$amt*$i;
mysql_query("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$edat','$amo_intr','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')") or die(mysql_error());
$lt=0;
while($lt<$nn)
{
$lt++;
$balance=$amt-($install-$amo_intr);
$amo_intr=$balance*$i;
$otherdat = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($edat)) . " +".$lt." month");
$otherdat = date("Y-m-d",$otherdat);
mysql_query("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$otherdat','$amo_intr','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `amo_intr` column?

Comment: Oh, and btw—"*dont comment about mysql syntax i know its depricated*"... it'd have been easier to simply swap mysql for mysqli than to have typed those 9 words.

Comment: Got the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your field `amo_intr` has type int.

I try to simultate it with this php script

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$nn=11;
$install=16.14;
$edat='2016-03-15';
$amt=100;
$i=0.12;
$actual_l='L8080';
$ecn='R555555';
$amo_intr=$amt*$i;
echo ("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$edat','".(int)$amo_intr."','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')")."\n";
$lt=0;
while($lt<$nn)
{
    $lt++;
    $balance=$amt-($install-$amo_intr);
    $amo_intr=$balance*$i;
    $otherdat = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($edat)) . " +".$lt." month");
    $otherdat = date("Y-m-d",$otherdat);
    echo ("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$otherdat','".(int)$amo_intr."','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')")."\n";
}
?>
```

And get such result

```
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-03-15','12','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-04-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-05-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-06-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-07-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-08-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-09-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-10-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-11-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-12-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2017-01-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2017-02-15','11','L8080','R555555','100')
```

Also there are error in your formula of $amo_intr calculation:

- You need to initialize balance before while loop `$balance = $amt;`
- And calculate balance inside loop with `$balance-=($install-$amo_intr);`

Working code for your:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$nn=11;
$install=16.14;
$edat='2016-03-15';
$amt=100;
$i=0.12;
$actual_l='L8080';
$ecn='R555555';
$amo_intr=$amt*$i;
echo ("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$edat','".$amo_intr."','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')")."\n";

$balance = $amt;
$lt=0;
while($lt<$nn)
{
    $lt++;
    $balance-=($install-$amo_intr);
    $amo_intr=$balance*$i;
    $otherdat = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($edat)) . " +".$lt." month");
    $otherdat = date("Y-m-d",$otherdat);
    echo ("insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('$otherdat','".$amo_intr."','$actual_l','$ecn','$amt')")."\n";
}
?>
```

With output

```
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-03-15','12','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-04-15','11.5032','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-05-15','10.946784','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-06-15','10.32359808','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-07-15','9.6256298496','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-08-15','8.843905431552','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-09-15','7.9683740833382','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-10-15','6.9877789733388','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-11-15','5.8895124501395','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2016-12-15','4.6594539441562','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2017-01-15','3.281788417455','L8080','R555555','100')
insert into amortize(amo_dat,amo_intr,lcode,ecn,amt) values('2017-02-15','1.7388030275496','L8080','R555555','100')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. You did a great job. Thanks again